# How can I test my camera-dependent android app on most devices?

Tags: testing, android, hardware, android-development

We are developing an app for taking photos faster. We do this by actually taking videos instead of photos and processing the individual images in the video on the fly and combine them to create a high-resolution image. Since this app is heavily dependent upon the hardware of the various devices, I was wondering how we could go about testing this on, say 50% of devices in one go? Are there for example groups of people that allow for all sorts of people to run tests on their devices? I would be willing to pay for each test on each on each device. What are my options?

Comment: A simple breakdown of services are: walk-in vendor labs, device rentals, full-service app testing services (where you provide test directions and the provider's staff will run down the instructions manually on the devices they own). What is more interesting is how you implement device-specific workarounds in your software, which is answered in the link mentioned by @gnat.

Comment: Keep in mind that despite your testing efforts, most "device-specific workaround" are discovered only after the public release of software. As a result, changes to the software workarounds can only be implemented after the initial release, and you have to prepare for rapid update releases on a continuous schedule as soon as a new workaround has been found and implemented.

Comment: Also see http://android.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

There are services out there for this sort of thing. [This article mentions some.](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/remote-test-your-android-apps-with-these-services/) Searching for something like "android device testing" should also lead you to some. Obviously you would need to evaluate which service gives you the functionality you need.